# In front of "ほうがいい," is it always past tense?

Tags: grammar, syntax

ほうがいい means:

the particular way "ほう"
is "が"
good "いい"

So, for example, if it looks like it's going to rain, I might say to a friend:

"今日は雨らしい。傘を持った方がいい。"

But what I'm curious is, why is "持った" past tense? It feels like it means, it WOULD'VE BEEN good to carry an umbrella, so it feels quite inappropriate tense-wise. I ask this question because there's no distinction between future and present tense in Japanese. For example,

"明日来る人は私の友達です。"
The dude coming tomorrow, is my friend.

"今、あそこから来る人は私の友達です。
That dude coming our way, is my friend.

So logically, I thought "take your umbrella" would be: 
"今日は雨らしい。傘を持つ方がいい。"

Instead of 
"今日は雨らしい。傘を持った方がいい。"

So, why is it that it's past tense?

Comment: If feels 100% appropriate tense-wise.  Wouldn't they say "It would be better if you brought an umbrella with you." in English when they are NOT talking about the past?

Comment: @l'électeur That's a good point. How would I say "I should've brought an umbrella" then? I have no idea how to put it.

Comment: It isn't always past tense though. For example.
`彼は怒ってるみたい。話をかけないほうがいい`
`彼は怒ってるみたい。話さないほうがいい`

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder [話]{はなし}をかけないほうがいい --> [話]{はな}しかけないほうがいい. You use the present tense for the negative ない. 「～～しないほうがいい」 not 「～～しなかったほうがいい」　(But don't ask me why)

Comment: @VladeKR "I should've brought an umbrella" would be 傘を持って行けば(or来れば)よかった or 傘を持って行ったら(or来たら)よかった etc.

Comment: @choco, Sorry about the mistype, that was essentially what I was trying to say. OP asked if it is always past tense, that was my way of weakly answering that it wasn't.

Comment: Worth noting that you can have the non-past positive form of verbs before ほうがいい, but they get a habitual/general interpretation as opposed to referring to a specific future event. It's a good question why things behave like this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This 〜た is the perfect, not past; that is, it's indicating a time before some reference time, rather than a time before speech time:

> 傘を持っていったほうがいい。
>   Lit. "Having brought an umbrella would be better."

That said, I don't think native speakers actually have such a complicated model (of comparing possible future worlds, one of which where you have brought an umbrella), but rather 〜たほうがいい has just become a way of making suggestions; that is, I think the 〜た has become mostly semantically bleached. However, I'm pretty sure this was the original function of 〜た here.

---

It is also possible to have the plain form of verbs before 〜ほうがいい, but they don't have a future interpretation but rather a "general" or "habitual" one.

> 傘を持っていくほうがいい。
>   "Bringing an umbrella is best."

That is, you're not making a suggestion about something to do at a future time, but making a more categorical statement.

I wish I had an explanation of *why* it's impossible for the plain form to have a future interpretation here, but I don't.

Comment: Aren't you trying to impose how English works on Japanese? Japanese apparently [doesn't have](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/past-tense-and-present-perfect-tense-with-the-ta-form/) a separate form for present perfect. Maybe it's just as the [other answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24441/18894) says that in Japanese, it is just customary to use the た-form when giving advice and making suggestions to others? Also I don't see how from 〜た indicating the perfect (if that is so) follows that subordinate tense depends on the matrix tense...

Comment: ...From what I know [that is so](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2020/08/tenses.html#sequence-of-tenses) regardless.

Comment: ...And what suggests a comparison?

Answer (score 7):

The suffix た does not automatically imply past tense.

In this free online dictionary, for instance, it lists **8** different meanings
/usages of 「た」.

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9F-556028#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Sure, you may not be able to read it, but it would at least give you a good sign that you should forget about your preconception "た = past tense" for a moment, would it not?  「た」 is important because it is complex.

Look at definition #6, for example.  「さあ、どんどん[歩]{ある}い**た**、歩い**た**」 is an imperative meaning "Keep walking; Don't stop!".  It is talking about the present and even immediate future.  That is not past tense at all.  Not even close to it.

Getting back to your question,

> 「(Verb phrase ending in た) + [方]{ほう}がいい」

is an extremely often-used expression that talks about the present and/or future -- again not the past.  This is not unique to Japanese at all.  You would say in English:

> "(If it indeed rains,) you will be glad you ***brought*** an umbrella with you."

Or would you still ask "Why use the past-tense 'brought'?"?

In Japanese, it is just customary to use the た-form when giving advice and making suggestions to others.

> 1.「傘を持って**いった**方がいい。」
>
> 2.「傘を持って**いく**方がいい。」

Both are actually correct sentences, but ***#1 would be heard much more often***.

Sentence #2 would sound like a stronger piece of advice than #1 to the native ear.

Comment: To any native English speaker, 'If it rains, you will be glad you brought an umbrella with you' has a definite element of past tense; the event might be in the actual future, but it's the past relative to another future point being talked about.

Comment: A better example would be, 'It's time I went away'; I can't tie a single past tense meaning to that.

Comment: According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar" https://www.amazon.co.jp/Dictionary-Basic-Japanese-Grammar/dp/4789004546 page 139 "Vinf・past 方がいい may express a stronger suggestion than Vinf・nonpast 方がいい". Is there consensus on which form is stronger?

Comment: "will be glad you brought" is bad grammar. Will should change to Would. Past is not mixed with future. A lot of native speakers do this, but it does not make it "correct"

Comment: @user1602 What's your source? The pattern is spot is PRESENT SIMPLE + WILL, which is used to talk about possible future situations.