# Past-tense inflection used for a future action

Tags: verbs

In this sentence

> 早く寝た方がいいですよ。

which is translated as

> You should go to sleep early.

I am confused about the reason in which the past tense inflection for 寝る is used. Is this a similar construct used in English where:

> It's better if you slept early

and

> It's better if you go to sleep early

virtually convey the same thing? I'm not sure if the first is correct English, but I often catch myself using it in colloquial situations. It seems to me here that both are equivalent ideas. Is my Japanese example similar to this? If so, would

> 早く寝る方がいいですよ。

be both correct and convey the same idea?

Comment: very good post, but I guess I'm still curious on why
早く寝る方がいいですよ。is incorrect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In front of "ほうがいい," is it always past tense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24426/in-front-of-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-is-it-always-past-tense) *EDIT*: 早く寝る方がいいですよ is also perfectly fine, but 寝た方が sounds a little stronger. (Perhaps 寝る方が = "It's better to sleep" vs 寝た方が = "You had better sleep")

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do all of these sentences imply equivalent meaning when looking at these verb forms: 寝る、寝た、寝ていった, 寝ていくor is there a nuance?
EDIT this seems to been have explained in the linked post, which I took a closer look at