# Is it possible to use a verb in なかった form when using ~た方がいい?

Tags: grammar

> *Hou ga ii* can follow verbs used for giving suggestions and advices. *To omoimasu*, which means 'I think', often follows this expression, making it sound less assertive. It follows verbs in the *ta*-form (plain affirmative past) and the *nai*-form (plain negative past). It can also follow verbs in the dictionary form, but the expression sounds more direct than when it is followed by verbs in the *ta*-form.

[Essential Japanese Grammar](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Essential_Japanese_Grammar.html?id=CUXRAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y), page 194.

From there on the book provides some examples, but no verb in plain negative past form, *nakatta*-form, is exemplified and, in my little experience, I have never come across such example.

In other words, given the sentence「子供の周りでタバコを吸わない方がいいね」, can we instead say「子供の周りでタバコを吸わなかった方がいいね」? That is, can we use 吸わなかった instead of 吸わない?

Comment: No, you can't. This has been asked and discussed several times here on this site. Check out [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42343/30454) to "Why is a verb in the past (た形) contradicted with ～ていない?"

Comment: @EddieKal I understand your point.  However, isn't 吸わなかった方がいい nevertheless grammatical, just that it says something different:  "It would have been better had you not smoked."  Right?

Comment: @A.Ellett: That would be `吸わない方がよかった`. `吸わなかった方がよかった` is acceptable, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use ～しなかった方がいい to express a future recommendation.

た in ～した方がいい is there to express the **perfect aspect**, not the past tense (See: [In front of "ほうがいい," is it always past tense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24426/5010)). You cannot attach た to ～しない in this construction because ～しない is not an action you can start or complete.